# How to mark folders as excluded in intellij but also commit to git?

Tags: intellij-idea

If I mark the dir as excluded and someone else checksout the project then the folder is not excluded. Same if I manually delete that folder. Any solutions for that? thanks

Exclude folder on intellij, checkout project in another folder. Folder is not excluded. Note: I didn't say git ignored, I said intellij excluded.

Comment: Sorry for the answer usign git as main response. I will try do it with intellij later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to delete a folder from remote repository then you need:

1. git rm -r --cached myFolder
2. Add folder to ignore/exclude by Right-click on folder | Git | Add to .gitignore
3. Commit these changes and push them to remote

Comment: I tried do it, but there is not possible to `ignore/exclude` folder after use `git rm -r folder-name` because there is no folder anymore. The only think that I can click after `git rm ...` is the file that was inside the folder. Can you add picture to your answer?

Comment: @BOTK3nny I am terribly sorry, I've forgotten to add "--cached" flag (see edited message). Please rollback changes, then run the command mentioned above and add a folder to the .gitignore

Comment: this will just exclude from git... my question is about intellij. Exclude folder on intellij, checkout project in another folder. Folder is not excluded. Note: I didn't say git ignored, I said intellij excluded. You are confusing the 2

Comment: @07mm8 I am sorry for the misunderstanding. If we are talking about excluding from Intellij that can be achieved by going to File | Project Structure | Modules, then the information about such exclusion stored in .idea folder in <project-name>.iml file. You need to commit it in order to share information about exclusion.

Comment: for some reason is not changing anything in .idea I already commit that